# interactively show/hide components in java

Tags: java, user-interface

I would like to create a java gui which has a main component and a side component which can be hidden by the user. can anybody help me where to look at (classes, methods) or even link to simple examples?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: Improve question, come with code samples and a realy question regarding the code. Thank you. @on topic google bro. Oracle has everything documented atleast this basic stuff

Comment: Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask such questions but I simply didn't know where to look. The hint with the split pane is exactly what I needed and saved me some hours.

Comment: When an answer given answers your question, click the button to mark it as "the answer" (or the best answer, or the earliest complete answer).  It helps other people who look at your question, and gives the person who answered some reputation points.  As for your question, a split pane allows the user to alter the width of an area with his pointing device; if what you want is something that slides out of the side of a UI on a button click, you probably want something else.

Comment: with the splitpane set to setOneTouchExpandable(true) one can show and hide the components by clicking on a little triangle. but if anybody knows something else to achieve this: let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a classic example for a split pane...